# Jquery validator - проверка на email или телефона в одном поле input

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-validation

Думаю использовать плагин JQuery validator чтобы не писать скрипт с нуля. По ТЗ задание такое.

> В поле можно будет ввести или номер телефона или mail. Соответственно
>   нужна будет проверка: номер телефона должен состоять минимум из 10
>   цифр (+ код страны). Если в значении будет присутствовать знак “@”, то
>   мы будем идентифицировать его как эл.адрес. Перед знаком “@”  и после
>   него должны быть расположены хотя бы по одному символу, а третий
>   символ справа должен быть точкой. Если значение заполнено не будет,
>   или будет заполнено не корректно, то будет выдаваться сообщение:
>   “Заполните это поле” (для номера телефона) или “Укажите верный
>   эл.адрес” (для эл.адреса).

Как сделать такую валидацию на JQuery Validator то есть на этом https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Никак, поле не может иметь одновременно 2 типа. Самый простой выход: все-таки сделать 2 поля для телефона и email'а. Посложнее: костылить свой валидатор

Comment: А есть ли такой плагин который может так сделать ?

Comment: Не видел таких, думаю что нет

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! Буду что то делать.

Comment: @Denis >третий символ справа должен быть точкой  Неверно, ибо [такие](https://www.reg.ru/domain/new/zonepedia/#expanders=thematic) зоны уже не редкость.

Answer (score 2):

Да вам даже jquery и валидаторы не нужны. Если только вы не хотите писать какой-то волшебный текст. Можно сделать через html pattern

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Something: <input type="text" name="something" pattern="\+[0-9]{1,4}[0-9]{1,10}|(.*)@(.*)\.[a-z]{2,5}" title="" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Пожалуйста, введите номер телефона или email')">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо реализовать и добавить своё правило в котором Вы будете проверять значение элемента на соответствие или номеру телефона или eMail. Используйте для этого [jQuery.validator.addMethod()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).
Примеров масса: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241145/jquery-validate-plugin-how-to-create-a-simple-custom-rule), [два](https://gist.github.com/kahneraja/d354b41408bf8d6267f0dc91a6c2e9a8), [три](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-custom-validation-rule-fieldpresent/)...

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так

Сначала проверяем на пустоту поля, затем проверяем в поле одни цифры или есть буквы, если есть буквы, то проверяем на правильность ввода e-mail, если только цифры, то проверяем кол-во введенных цыфр

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#text').click(function() {
    var val = $('#input').val();
    if(val != '') {
      if(/[^[0-9]/.test(val)){
        var pattern = /^([a-z0-9_\.-])+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{2,4}\.)?[a-z]{2,4}$/i;
        if(pattern.test(val)){
          $('#valid').text('E-mail введен верно');
        } else {
          $('#valid').text('Не верно введен e-mail');
        }
      } else {
        if(val.length >= 10) {
          $('#valid').text('Телефон введен верно');
        } else {
          $('#valid').text('Не верно введен номер телефона');
        }
      }
    } else {
      $('#valid').text('Поле input не должно быть пустым');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input">
<button id="text">Test</button>
<div id="valid"></div>
```